# Java Использование Comparator в сортировке

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать Comparator при сортировке массива.
Дано: массив строк

```
Strings [] strings = {"c", "a", "d", "b"};
```

Поставлена следующая задача:

> Проинициализируйте переменную comparator
>
> 1. Создайте класс, реализующий интерфейс Comparator. Подумайте о
>      контексте, в котором будет использоваться экземпляр.
> 2. Проинициализируйте переменную comparator экземпляром созданного
>      класса.

```
Comparator comparator = null;
```

И далее:

> Отсортируйте массив strings по убыванию
>
> 1. Подумайте о том, какой Comparator следует передать, чтобы массив
>      сортировался по убыванию.

```
sort.sort(strings, comparator);
```

Реализоваться должно с использованием класса, в котором различные способы сортировки:

```
public class Sorting {
    public void sort(Object[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
    }

    public void sort(Object[] array, Comparator comparator) {
        /* тут должен быть код */
    }
}
```

Не могу понять логику, как переопределить метод compare в собственном классе, и что реализовать в методе с сортировкой по убыванию?

Comment: Вы компаратор используете совсем не по назначению. Если хотите алгоритм сортировки вставками, то реализуйте его отдельным методом без компаратора. А если вам прям жизненно необходимо использовать в вашем случае компаратор, то можно сделать так:
`Sort sort = new Sorting()
sort.sort(strings, Comparator.comparing(x -> x))`

Comment: мне нужен компаратор из собственного класса

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
Sort sort = new Sorting();
Comparator comparator = new Compare();
sort.sort(strings, comparator);
```

И далее в классе Sorting:

```
 @Override
    public void sort(Object[] array, Comparator comparator){
        Arrays.sort(array, comparator.reversed());
    }
```